# How one can explain the Generation gap between David and Goliath?

Tags: king-david, book-of-ruth

Is there a midrash that explains how David meets Goliath, since the **time gap** between the two is huge? Goliath is Orpah's son (II Sam. 21;I Sam. 17) and David is the great-grandson of Ruth, Orpah's sister (Ruth Rabbah 2:9) or at least her sister-in-law. There would be 3 generations of difference. How can we put both in the same scene, as our sages did? Thank you.

Comment: Goliath would be the same generation as David's grandfather Oved. I've met some of my grandfather's cousins.

Comment: Of all the generation gaps in Torah, this is perhaps the least notable.

Comment: Dovid was at oldest a teenager at the time whereas Golayis probably in his fifties like most senior officers are

Comment: "_Goliath is Orpah's son (II Sam. 21;I Sam. 17)_ ..." That makes it sound like the statement is explicit in the text of the cited chapters. It is not so. _I Sam. 17_ doesn't mention Goliath's parentage, and the Goliath mentioned in _II Sam. 21_ , was (a) son of the Rafah (**ה**רפה) and (b) killed by Elhanan the son of Jaare-oregim the Beth-lehemite (אלחנן בן יערי ארגים בית הלחמי; v. 19), so maybe not the one David killed before he was king, Where do _you_ get that Goliath (that David meets in _I Sam. 17_ ) is Orpah's son?